# Calculating ExpandableListView height at the initial lifecycle

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I had a problem that stems from the fact that Android has certain difficulty with nested scrolling elements.

I have a ScrollView that hosts a horizontal RecyclerView and an ExpandableListView just beneath it. 
The issue I encountered was that the ScrollView didn't scroll.

I fixed it by :
 1. setting fixed height to the RecyclerView.
 2. calculating the ExpandableListView height with each group item click.
 Like this:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });

private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group)) || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group)))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++)
                {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,listView);
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
        if (height < 10)
            height = 200;
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Problem :
since I calculate the listview height only on group item click, when I just open the fragment and up until I click on a group item, the ScrollView doesn't work.
I have found that calculating the height of the ExpandableListView adapter in onCreateView is problematic since it is still empty at that point.

Any ideas would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait until the view has been laid out, you can use 
a [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html). For example :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    final View someView = findViewById(R.id.some_id);
    someView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            // the values are now available
            int mesuredHeight = someView.getMeasuredHeight();
            int height = someView.getHeight();

            // done, remove the observer
            someView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: though it does affect the performance.. it seems this is invoked every time I touch the screen.. and if I add an if statement so that it only calls the method the first time, the problem returns.

Comment: actually the listener is invoked in an endless loop. without touching even

Comment: It was to avoid this kind of problems that the listener is removed. Does it help if you remove the listener **before** touching the views ?

Comment: kind of. The performance is good again, but the ExpandableListView's height becomes really small.. and the scrolling between the items there obviously is annoying and not applicable for a release version

Comment: So it means multiple layout pass are needed until the right size can be calculated. This approach will probably not work without ugly hacks. I wonder if putting a `ListView` in a `Scrollview` is a good idea in the first place. Anyway I suggest that you unaccept this answer, sorry.

Comment: I have found other solution, which is checking the adapter's size in the onGlobalLayout callback method, and only when the adapter.getGroupCount is >0 , I call the setHeight method and remove the listener..
It seems to be less affecting the performance and working..
Regarding the question whether it was wise or not to put the listView inside a ScrollView in the first place - I agree with you, but that's the design I have been given to implement(and in iOS it had no problems of that sort at all) so I all I can blame now is either Google or the design team ;)

Comment: by the way, you can edit your answer with my solution(adding that 'if' statement) aforementioned and I'll accept the answer again